# Operation point - Amplifier

Tags: amplifier

Given this circuit:

**vs is small signal voltage.**

[image]

I calculated the Operation Point and got that Vout must be equal to 0.
Now let us say I want to put a capacitor in series with R2.

Does this change my operation point?

I still get that Vout must be equal to 0.

**The upper and lower Voltages of the Amplifier are 5 and -5.**

Comment: What value VS voltage source has?

Comment: @G36 I edited the question. VS is a small signal voltage source so it won't affect my operation point. Take it as a 0.

Comment: Well if Vs is 0V (replace it with a short circuit) then yes Vo = 0V and adding a capacitor in series with R2 doesn't change it.

Comment: @G36 Even though my amplifier's lower and upper voltages are -5 and 5 volts?

Comment: The amplifier is ideal. V-=V+.

Comment: Yep, supply voltage doesn't matter here in this case.

Comment: Can you show us your expression for Vout?

Comment: Also, have you notice that Is = Vs/R5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bias point will be ground, as determined by R4.  Whether R2 is cap coupled or not won't affect the bias point, but it will give you a low pass pole and a zero.